# Add metadata to SharePoint sitecollection

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Are there any way where we can add metadata to a SharePoint online modern site collection, we would like to add either tags or property bag properties to the site collection and have search index these metadata much like indexed properties we had in earlier on prem site collections. Is this possible in any way using power shell, rest API or any other form of SharePoint API?

We had the opportunity in the old UI / on premise by add a propertybag entry and set it to "indexed".

Answer (score 0):

I think if in SP Online You disable NoScript using one of the methods mentioned [here](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-enable-custom-scripts-for-a-sharepoint-online-site-collection/). You should be still able to add a property bag value to Site Collection using PnP Powershell method
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnppropertybagvalue?view=sharepoint-ps

with -Indexed switch param You make the property bag value indexed as You wanted

Comment: Hey Adam. The "index" propertybag will work on classic SharePoint site. But not on new 